# Could Batman be arrested for driving an unregistered car without a license?

Tags: dc, batman, laws

Batman frequently drives his Batmobile on the public roads of Gotham. Is it unregistered? And does he actually have a license for it that he could show if Commissioner Gordon or another cop decided to pull him over? I mean, he can't very well show Bruce Wayne's license.

I wonder because at various times the Gotham City Police Department have not been on good terms with Batman. Even if he's in the clear on his vigilante activities, it seems like he could be arrested at any time should they want to actually enforce their driving laws.

So could Batman be arrested for driving an unregistered car without a license? Or are there special circumstances that legally allow him to do that?

I am most interested in mainstream DC Comics (e.g. *Detective Comics*), but other media would be interesting supplementary information to an answer that includes that.

Comment: I find it interesting that you're focused on Batman's drivers license when I'm willing to bet Bruce Wayne's fortune that the Batmobile is unregistered.

Comment: Since Batman saves Gotham on a regular basis, I doubt that he'd ever be pulled over (except perhaps if driving very erratically). I doubt not having a license would be a ticketable offense. However, since Bruce Wayne/Batman is a law-abiding citizen, I wouldn't be surprised if there were two different licenses owned: one with Bruce Wayne's picture, and the other of Batman.

Comment: Because the title instantly made me think of the Adam West show, I'm going to share this tangentially-related tidbit: the Batmobile was [once impounded](https://youtu.be/FAjt-Vhmgwg?t=3m4s) for not having windshield wipers

Comment: @Ellesedil Fair point! I dunno, for some reason I thought about the license instead of the car. I've incorporated both.

Comment: I know Batman is a great driver, but it's hard to believe he's never been in an accident. Does he carry regular insurance, or does he self-insure? For the self-insurance application, does Batman have a bank account in his own name? Does he have a Social Security number?

Comment: @user14111 Well, [he's got a Bat Credit Card](https://youtu.be/dcukDDDhuYk), so maybe the credit agency gives him car insurance too!

Comment: @T-1000'sSon _"Since Batman saves Gotham on a regular basis, I doubt that he'd ever be pulled over"_ Depending on which canon you follow, Batman is not liked by everyone. The Nolan movies very much stress the point that no one likes Batman, especially not the police (with the exceptions of Gordon and Blake) _"However, since Bruce Wayne/Batman is a law-abiding citizen"_ He's a vigilante, and the Nolan movies again very much explore that Batman is on the run from the police who are (officially) required to chase him.

Comment: Police-officer 1 to Police-officer 2:  *Let me get this straight. Your perp is secretly a vigilante who spends his nights beating criminals to a pulp with his bare hands; and your plan, is to 'arrest' this person?*

Comment: Now I really want to post a question "What crimes could Batman be arrested for, and what sentence might he get". But I suspect it would be closed as a list question, and probably a long one.

Comment: @Flater I was thinking more along the lines of Adam-West Batman when I responded: liked, respected, etc., by basically everyone except the thugs and goons of the city.

Comment: Sure, but you still have to catch him first....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely!  In New York state, which I'm guessing will have the most relevant laws, penalties for driving an unlicensed vehicle are these:

- Can be forced to pay a fine ranging from $40-$300
- Can incur an $88-$93 surcharge
- Can face up to 15 days in jail

That's if you're 60 days or fewer out of compliance.  If you've been driving an unregistered vehicle for longer, the fines and possible jail time add up.

All that said...

**Penalties for being a vigilante and beating people up are probably a smidge higher.**  Priorities, man.  ;D

Edit:  Forgot to add about driving unlicensed.  Bruce has a license, but Batman can't use it...

Driving without a license is a misdemeanor offense listed under Section 509 of the New York Vehicle and Traffic Code (VTC). Violations will result in the following penalties:

A monetary fine not less than $75 and no greater than $300, OR
Imprisonment for a time period not to exceed 15 days, OR
Both the fine and jail time

Comment: "Bruce has a license, but Batman can't use it..." Well, Batman could. But he understandably wouldn't want to. Of course, if Batman was indeed taken into custody somehow, I don't think Batman's secret identity is going to all that secret anymore, so I'd assume the "driving without a license" aspect would be dropped.

Comment: While I like this, I think the question author was looking for any in-universe thinking on the matter.

Comment: This is a good and detailed answer, however, the question was *could Batman be arrested*?  Laws aside, in order to be arrested, the police would have to *catch him first,* and that's not such an easy task when we're talking about a guy who's car - in various continuities - has been known to spew smoke screens, drive up walls, jump rooftops and convert into a motorcycle on demand...

Comment: Why New York, when Gotham is [clearly in New Jersey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/where-is-gotham-city-located?noredirect=1&lq=1)....

Comment: @JeremyFrench I don't know if there's any canon on this kind of local law, but I think it's pretty much in-universe to say that the cops are at best ... *conflicted* about the Dark Knight.  In the Dark Knight Returns, they make a big deal over the vigilante debate, and there is some pretty good distinction drawn between the Gordon and Yindel administrations.  It takes a complete breakdown of order before Yindel realizes that she can't bring herself to stop him.  "He's ... too big."

Comment: In most incarnations of Batman, he has the support of the police commissioner (James Gordon), so the cops wouldn't touch him even if they regularly see him commit felonies and crimes (while preventing much more serious crimes).