# Was Batman ever issued a ticket for his infractions?

Tags: dc, batman

This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169912/could-batman-be-arrested-for-driving-an-unregistered-car-without-a-license) asks if Batman could be arrested for driving an unregistered vehicle, in the real world. The answer, of course, being a clear yes.

In the comics, Batman commits several infractions on a daily basis, some of which that come to mind are over-speeding, damage to public property, driving an unlicensed/unregistered vehicle etc.

So, has the Gotham City Police Department ever issued Batman a ticket for his infractions?

Comment: [Yes?](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2119706/Holy-traffic-infraction-Batman-Man-dressed-Dark-Knight-pulled-Batmobile-tags.html)

Comment: Minor traffic infractions are the least of Gotham's problems if we really get down to it but by and large they overlook it. And when they don't and he's ruled "illegal" they can't really stop him anyway. And in any case who are they going to send a ticket to?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot to the same holder of the Batcard.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That article was what got me thinking in the first place.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot idk, by projecting the ticket in the sky using the Bat-signal?

Comment: You would first have to catch Batman to issue him a ticket i guess

Comment: According to [the first quote here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519510/characters/nm0001842) Batman was very zealous about parking fees, at least. Maybe he regularly paid his tickets anonymously.

Comment: How many times did the Batmobile catch a flat?

Comment: “if Batman could be arrested for driving an unregistered vehicle” — they tried in *The Dark Knight Rises*, and he ironically evaded capture using another presumably-unregistered vehicle.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen batman come back to the batmobile and see a parking ticket on it.  Either in the 60s show or the cartoon?  It was played as a gag..  (may have been remembering the episode Kakturus linked)

Comment: You're sure the Batmobile isn't registered to a corporation, owned by another offshore corporation, with "obscure" ownership?

Comment: Let's not forget his almost daily discharging of weapons within the city, air space violations, damage to personal property, interfering with agency functions, being a nuisance, etc. The only thing that differentiates Batman from the villains he chases down is public opinion. On a technical level, he is in many ways a worse violator of laws than the bad guys because they are at least caught or thwarted. Batman runs rampant. Who knows if anyone has taken a stray bullet from the bat cannons or been crushed by a slab of falling concrete caused by his careless actions.

Comment: Adam West's Batman was rather more conscientious about these things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9snCPqMpUsA

Comment: @rid You did, and it was 60s Batman. I can't find the clip online, but two cops find the Batmobile illegally parked (maybe the meter ran out). One of them hasn't heard of Batman and just wants to ticket it. The other one has, and doesn't want to because Batman has connections to Gordon and O'Hara. Batman then shows up. I remember it being hilarious. I posted a quick link to another funny "the Batmobile and traffic violations" clip above.

Comment: You can't really ticket the Batmobile without a license plate. It should be towed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Batman has received parking tickets on multiple occasions.

In *[All Star Section 8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/All_Star_Section_Eight_Vol_1)*, a *What-If* comic published by DC.

[image]

And in *[Batman and Robin Adventures #18](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_%26_Robin_Adventures_Vol_1_18)*:

[image: Batman gets a parking ticket for parking too close to fire hydrant]

Albeit the ticket turns out to be illegitimate

> [image]

Comment: "Albeit the ticket turns out to be illegitimate" - Debatable.  In the first panel at least the batmobile is clearly blocking the entire hydrant.  Any halfway professional traffic cop would ticket that. :)

Comment: @aroth, the infraction appears to be real there, yes. But the ticket itself still seems very suspect. The two are not the same thing :)